# How can I print the amount of times 'while' was executed?

Tags: java, do-while

I'm writing a code which will be multiplying 'x' until it'll reach the 'y'.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int y = scan.nextInt();

    do {
        x = (int)(x*(1.1f));

    }
        while(x < y);

    }
```

In the answer I have to get the amount of times 'while' was executed. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: You can use a counter variable.

Comment: just add a print statement

Answer (score 2):

So general approach would be, create variable `i` of type `int`, and increment it at the end of while loop block (this one looks simple actually). So overall, I'd do it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int y = scan.nextInt();
    int i = 0;
    do {
        x = (int)(x*(1.1f));
        i++;
    } while (x < y);
    System.out.println("Loop executed " + i + " times.");
}
```

If you can use `for` loop, check out this way of solving your problem:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int y = scan.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        for (; x < y; i++)
            x = (int)(x*(1.1f));
        System.out.println("Loop executed " + i + " times.");
    }
}
```

Thanks to the fact that for loop allows execution of some statement every iteration, you can increment your counter variable everytime loop is looping (this can solve some cases where you use `continue;` statement).

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to find out how many times `x` should be multiplied by `1.1` for it to get larger than `y`. Or in other words, to what power should `1.1` be raised in order for it to get larger than `y/x`.

Therefore, an alternative to using a counter would be observing that you need to calculate log<sub>1.1</sub>(y/x) and round it up to the next `int`, which in Java can be done with:

```
Math.ceil (Math.log ((double)y/x) / Math.log (1.1));
```

Comment: Clever one! Nice.